# Launch an application for blind people

Tags: android, launch, voice-recognition

I'm going to build an android application for blind people. As it is for blind people it should be launched using voice command or another access method. Android can launch an application from another application using voice commands as I know. I want to know, can my application  be opened alone? If yes,how it can be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean with "alone"?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "opened alone"?

Comment: @greywolf82  This application for blind people.So is there any method to start my application without touching the application icon? I only found that can be done in another application using voice commands like "open <app name>". But it requires another application. Here I can't use another application because blind one will not able to see that application too. So there should be a process always running after the device is started,am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can start your application at startup using BOOT_COMPLETED intent and a broadcast receiver. At that point you could start your foreground service to have the "always listening" even if you have to use some offline engine for speech to text like PocketSphinx engine.